# Передать данные в контроллер

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, ajax

Имеется форма веб-приложения, хочу передать данные с нее в объект внутрь ajax, чтобы он в последствии передал их в контроллер, но только примерно представляю как это сделать

Код формы:

```
<form action="" method="post" Name="test" id="form">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <label for="FName"> Фамилия</label>
            <input type="text" name="FName" placeholder="Фамилия" id="FName" onkeyup='checkParams()' onchange="validName(this)" />
            <div id="error" class="error"></div>
            <br />
            <label for="Name"> Имя</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Имя" id="Name" onkeyup='checkParams()' onchange="validName(this)" />
            <div class="error" id="error2"></div>
            <br />
            <label for="LName"> Отчество</label>
            <input type="text" name="LName" placeholder="Отчество" id="LName" />
            <div id="error"> </div>
            <br />
            <label for="Opisanie"> Описание</label>
            <input type="text" name="Opisanie" placeholder="Описание" id="Opisanie" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="Date"> Дата рождения</label>
            <input type="date" name="Date" placeholder="Дата рождения" id="Date" onchange="validate_date(this);" />
            <div id="error"></div>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Отправить заявку" disabled />
            </td>
```

Код Ajax:

```
  $('input#submit').click(function () {
            //собрать данные с формы в объект


            console.log(1);
            // добавить объект для передачи

            var url = '@Url.Action("Register", controllerName: "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&"),
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $('#form').html(result);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log('ошибка' + error);
                }
            });
            console.log(2);
        });
```

Код контроллера:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(WebApplication4.Models.ValForm model)
        {
            using (var sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\TestProject\Testf.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(model.FName + ' ' + model.Name + ' ' + model.LName + ' ' + model.Opisanie + ' ' + model.Date + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return PartialView("RegisterForm");
        }
```